# How to run log analytics query using azure api?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-log-analytics, azure-api-apps

I have been trying to run a log analytics query using Azure API but its returns some error
{
"error": {
"message": "Valid authentication was not provided",
"code": "AuthorizationRequiredError",
"correlationId": "27301475d-cc29-4288-ae61-29e77d6d05cb"
}
}

this was the request I have been trying

https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/34567824-3432rewfsdewt435-3424jhh-dsa-/query?query=search in (ContainerLog) "*search_data*"| where TimeGenerated > datetime("2020-09-03")| project LogEntry  & Authorization=Bearer 0000000000000000000000000000

if you guys know anything please help me
Thank you

Comment: How do you acquire a token?

Comment: Check this url(https://dev.loganalytics.io/) on how to query using Azure API. It has information on how to obtain token to pass to the API.

Comment: https://dev.loganalytics.io/oms/documentation/1-Tutorials/1-Direct-API   this how I got the token

Comment: "search in (ContainerLog) "*singlemicro*"

| where TimeGenerated > datetime("2020-09-03")

| project LogEntry"





I have tried to execute this query using rest API but it shows some authentication error.



can you please explain how to get the authentication key?



also an example code 

Thank you @PeterBons

Comment: I think you need to check all the steps from the doc. The message points to an error in the configuration. To get a token and call the api using c# take a look on how I do it [here](https://github.com/Ibis-Software/Azure-Monitor-Alerts-To-MsTeams/blob/master/src/AppInsightsToTeams/AlertProcessors/LogAnalytics/LogAnalyticsAlertProcessor.cs#L87)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use Azure Log Analytics REST API to do a query, we need to user `Authorization=Bearer {token}` as request Headers.  For more details, please refer to [here](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/1-Tutorials/Direct-API).
[image]

For example

1. Register Azure AD application
2. Configure API permissions for the AD application
   [image]
3. Give the AAD Application access to our Log Analytics Workspace. Please assign `Log Analytics Reader` role to the AD application
4. Get access token

```
POST /<your tenant id>/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type =client_credentials
&client_id=<>
&client_secret=<>
&resource=https://westus2.api.loganalytics.io
```

4. Call the api

a. [POST method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/dataaccess/query/execute)

```
POST https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/query
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "query": ""
}
```

[image]

b. [Get method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/dataaccess/query/get)

```
GET https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/query?query={query}

Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See also [Valid authentication was not provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217464/valid-authentication-was-not-provided/72461530#72461530) thread's answer:

> ## Use API key
>
> You may also create **API key** and use it for your request:
>
> 1. Go to Application Insights in Azure Portal
> 2. Click on *API Access* blade under *Configure* section
> 3. Create new API key
> 4. Use it in REST API calls in a header with Key = `x-api-key`