# Valid authentication was not provided

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I am stuck on step 2.4 of this [wiki](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/1-tutorials/direct-api)

In the previous step, I get a valid token.

Why do I get "Valid authentication was not provided"?

I added a header called Authorization - see picture.

What am i missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use Azure Log Analytics REST API to do a query, we need to use `Authorization=Bearer eyJ....` as request Headers.  For more details, please refer to [here](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/1-Tutorials/Direct-API).

For example

1. Register Azure AD application
2. Configure API permissions for the AD application
   [image]
3. Give the AAD Application access to our Log Analytics Workspace. Please assign `Log Analytics Reader` role to the AD application
4. Get access token

```
POST /<your tenant id>/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type =client_credentials
&client_id=<>
&client_secret=<>
&resource=https://westus2.api.loganalytics.io
```

4. Call the api

```
POST https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/{workspaceId}/query
Authorization: Bearer ey...
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "query": ""
}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, that fixes my problem. I was missing &resource=https://westus2.api.loganalytics.io

Comment: FYI, you might get a "The 'resource' request parameter is not supported." error like i was getting.

In this case, use `scope=https://api.loganalytics.io/.default` instead and it'll work if you did the permissions right ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Use API key

You may also create **API key** and use it for your request:

1. Go to Application Insights in Azure Portal
2. Click on *API Access* blade under *Configure* section
3. Create new API key
4. Use it in REST API calls in a header with Key = `x-api-key`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id=<client id>&scope=https://api.loganalytics.io/.default&client_secret=<client secret>&grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

to get this to work, i.e.:

```
POST /<your tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=<>
&client_secret=<>
&scope=https://api.loganalytics.io/.default
```

I hope this helps someone :)  It took way too long for me to figure this out lol.