# How to get access token for subscription in a different tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, httprequest, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I'm trying to use "invoke an http request" action in power automate to query a log analytics workspace. I have access to perform this from azure portal. I referred this *[Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/dataaccess/query/execute?tabs=HTTP)* to get the URI. But when I try to execute the flow, I get the below error:

[image]

Complete error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The provided authentication is not valid for this resource",
    "code": "InvalidTokenError",
    "correlationId": "45e0ff0c-01f1-4ea5-a11d-ec6ce2d71b8b",
    "innererror": {
      "code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant",
      "message": "The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/687f51c3-0c5d-4905-84f8-97c683a5b9d1/'. It must match one of the tenants 'https://sts.windows.net/2f4a9838-26b7-47ee-be60-ccc1fdec5953/,https://sts.windows.net/a6eb2ff5-3009-4bfc-b769-24a2f82c1913/' associated with this subscription. Please use any authority (URL) from 'https://login.windows.net/2f4a9838-26b7-47ee-be60-ccc1fdec5953,https://login.windows.net/a6eb2ff5-3009-4bfc-b769-24a2f82c1913' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later."
    }
  }
}
```

The analytics workspace that I'm trying to query is not under my AAD tenant. It is under another tenant/directory, which I have access from portal. How can I get the access token so that I can execute this query?

I have already tried the action "Run query and list results" in power automate, which gave the same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below points:

1. Please check if you have  multiple subscription .So while
   requesting access token , it is the tenant which is not part of the
   subscription that you might have selected. In such a case try to
   change the settings and make your subscription map to the directory
   which you want to use.
2. In some cases browser tries or attempts to get an access token from
   already logged in tenant .So If its under same subscription, try to
   check  after `clearing the cache`
3. You can also put required tenant ID in the `enviroment settings` of
   your particular app, using  DefaultAzureCredential()
4. Or Configure the authority defining the tenantId
   [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant-id%7D) for multiple tenants
5. Signing in once to access to all the Azure Log Analytics data from
   all tenant may not be feasible.It may require reauthentication .

Check this way to get
the accesss token for that particular tenant [Request an
authorization token - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/authentication-authorization) and use the
token to call the log analytics workspace

**References:**

1. [Query - Execute - REST API (Azure Log Analytics) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/dataaccess/query/execute?tabs=HTTP#cross-workspace)
2. [azure log analytics - Valid authentication was not provided - Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217464/valid-authentication-was-not-provided/72461530#72461530)